# nginx caching ajax

Tags: ajax, caching, nginx

I'm using nginx for proxy cache and I'm having trouble to make it cache some ajax requests.
Nginx are making cache correctly for all pages but not for ajax requests.

The uri for ajax requests are like: /process/leaveyourmessage/getMessages?id=XX

My location config is:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://mydomain.com:8080;
    proxy_cache microcache;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 5s;
    proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

On the http block I've added:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2
                 keys_zone=microcache:5m max_size=1000m;
```

Anyone know what could be the problem?
My back end is apache + php

---

I've found the problem. Nginx respect cache-control and expires header and those ajax was sending it.

Writing down "proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;" made it work.

Comment: With ajax, are you using get or post requests? Nginx will not cache post requests.

Comment: @Kev what is localized here ?

Comment: @PavelNiedoba it's an old way of closing questions that, such as in this example, OP answered it themselves but in the body of the question *and* it was kinda old and the OP never came back to create a self-answer.

Comment: Just to list all headers that can affect this issue:
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires X-Accel-Expires Set-Cookie Vary;